# Validate file than upload file - multer

Tags: node.js, multer

I want to run some custom validation on `.xlsx` before upload. I have written the basic validation for now but my upload not working.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const multer = require('multer');

const router = express.Router();
const uploadExcel = require('./excelMiddleware');

const multerS = multer();
const upload = multer({
  dest:'excel',
  fileFilter(res, file, cb){
    if(!file.originalname.match(/\.(xls|xlsx)$/)){
      return cb(new Error('Please upload a excel file'));
    }
    cb(undefined, true)
  }
}).single('file');

router.post('/upload', multerS.single('file'), uploadExcel, upload, (req, res) => {
  upload(req, res, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
  })
  res.send('<h1>file uploaded</h1>')
})

router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send('<h1>Page not found</h1>')
})

app.use(router);

app.listen(8000, ()=> {
  console.log('Server stared')
})
```

**excelMiddleware.js**

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');
const { CONTACT } = require('./column.config');
const _ = require('lodash');

const uploadExcel = (req, res, next) => {
    try{
      const columnMapper = CONTACT;
      const workbook = XLSX.read(req.file.buffer, {type:'buffer'});
      const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames;
      const excelJson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName[0]]);
      if(!excelJson.length) {
          throw Error("Blank sheet");
      }
      const columnCheck = Object.keys(excelJson[0]);
      const isColumnEqual = _.isEqual(columnMapper, columnCheck);
      if(!isColumnEqual){
        throw Error("Blank sheet");
      }
      next();
    }
    catch(e){
      console.log(e)
      return res.status(400).send({error:e.message});
    }
}


module.exports = uploadExcel;
```

Comment: Do you require both `multerS.single('file')` and `upload`?

Comment: yes, as my uploadExcel middleware needs the file object

Comment: Yes that's true, but can't you access file like you do in upload excel middleware i.e req.file instead of using multer().single('file')

Comment: run upload as your first middleware, and then uploadExcel. There's no need for multerS.single('file')